# How to create bins same density in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I need to create n bins in Pandas, provided that each bin has the same density (or area if I plot it with an histogram)

I have checked

```
pandas.cut()
```

however, this only allow me to create n bins, but it doesn't help with the bins' density.

For example, if I have the following distribution
[image]
and I select 4 bins, I would expect that I have higher granularity for smaller values, whilst the last bin would probably be [12.5, 20].
In other words, I want to keep the bins' area constant.

Any function I can use with pandas?

Comment: You may want to look at [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html)

Comment: @harvpan I've already checked qcut, however it again ignores the frequency